# Reading from JAVA socket slower than Python

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I'm trying to read the data from Python server using TCP socket. For this, client in python is already written and I'm supposed to write Android code for this. I've tried different approaches in JAVA, but I'm seeing that Socket reading in JAVA code that I've written is very slow.

I am overwriting buffer in some cases as I am only concerned with number of bytes that I am receiving not the actual data.

Following is the snippet of socket reading in Python client

```
        buffer_len = 0
        print str(tcp.response_len) + " start  " + str((time.time()-timeOrigin)*1000)
        while True:
            buffer_len += len(self.sock.recv(4096))
            print str(buffer_len) + " of " + str(tcp.response_len)
            if buffer_len >= tcp.response_len:
                break
```

Following are the couple of things that I have tried in JAVA  :

```
            while (totalRead < RS.getResponse_len()) {
                                    //dataInputStream is of type DataInputStream
                int bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer, totalRead, RS.getResponse_len() - totalRead);
                Log.d("Response", "Total read : " + totalRead + " of " + RS.getResponse_len());
                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Data stream ended prematurely");
                }
                totalRead += bytesRead;
            }
```

With small buffer size :

```
                while (totalRead < RS.getResponse_len()) {
                int bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer, 0, 4096);

                Log.d("Response", "Total read : " + totalRead + " of " + RS.getResponse_len());
                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Data stream ended prematurely");
                }
                totalRead += bytesRead;
            }
```

I also tried using readFully instead of read too but reading was still slow.

Then I tried reading data using ReadableByteChannel as follows  :

```
            ByteBuffer lenBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
            //SocketChannel.open();
            ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(client.socket.getInputStream());
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while (totalRead < RS.getResponse_len()) {
                bytesRead = channel.read(lenBuf);
                lenBuf.clear();
                Log.d("Response", "Total read : " + totalRead + " of " + RS.getResponse_len());
                totalRead += bytesRead;
            }
```

But I am not seeing any significant improvements in reading.

Can you please point mistakes in mu code or suggest me some alternatives for faster reading?

Thank you.

Comment: In each of your code snippet, do you know how many times it loops to fully read the content? Ie. does all data get read in only one loop?

Comment: In my case, I am sending request to server before the start of while loop and it's sending data to me. Yes, server starts sending data and my intention is to read all the data sent by server before I move forward. Does this answer your question? Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question. Let me ask another way, how many times do you see the log "Response Total Read:...." to fully read one response.

Comment: While using read method to read data from server, this log message is getting printed around 1400 times and I'm trying to read about 14 MB of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what RS.getResponse_len() do. I can only hope that it doesn't loop to count the length. But one improvement in your 2nd snippet is this. Your original code would have allocated enough buffer size to accomodate the entire reponse length. You can make use of your buffer size as Response_len(). You would have something like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[RS.getResponse_len()];
int totalRead = 0;
while(totalRead<buffer.length) {
    int bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer,totalRead,buffer.length-totalRead);
    if(bytesRead<0) throw new IOException("Data stream ended prematurely");

    totalRead+=bytesRead;
}
```

You said you will be reading 14MB of data. In that case you will need to read into a smaller buffer and process that buffer.

If you just want to read the contents and do nothing with it. Try this

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10240]; // 10Kb buffer
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(dataInputStream);
int totalBytesToRead = RS.getResponse_len();
while(totalBytesToRead>0) {
    int bytesRead = bis.read(buffer);
    if(bytesRead<0) throw new IOException("Data stream ended prematurely");
    totalBytesToRead -= bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem. RS.getResponse_len() is O(1) operation.

Comment: I have also tried this but still I am not seeing much improvement. I have added code snippet in question.

Comment: It seems you are not doing anything with the buffer. Are you doing this purely to test how fast it can read from the input stream? Is your dataInputStream a BufferedInputStream? If not, try wrapping it with BufferedInputStream to minimize the underlying IO calls.

Comment: Sorry for really late reply. Yeah, I am kind of trying to see how fast data can be read. My dataInputStream was not wrapped with BufferedInputStream. I tried wrapping it but still the data reading speed is very slow. I also tried increasing buffer size but it was also not helpful.

Comment: Have you tried only calling RS.getResponse_len() once to get the content length and re-use it? Other than that, I got no more ideas as to why you say the speed is slow as you're just reading off the stream. How slow is slow? What is the time difference between PHP and Java implementation?

Comment: I found that it's not JAVA problem. I think it's Android problem.  Running same code(without changing any kind of socket reading code) that I've written for Android on my computer gives me download speed of 1 Mbps while on Android it's giving me speed of 200 Kbps. I'll mark your answer as correct and open another thread for android specific problem. Thanks

Comment: When you say it is android problem, are you testing it on the same network? If you use GSM network, it could be slower than your home broadband.